# I want to add a new column in Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I want to add a new datetime column to a file.
I would like to use the "add column" feature in the source dataset of the synapse pipeline to store the date the file was copied.
However, when I use the datetime function in Syanpse, the return value is a string, so the copy activity mapping can only be mapped as a string type. I want to store this in datetime type.
Is there a better way to do this?
The error message is "The column was not found" .

Also, the pipeline is copying data to SFTP > Raw > Processed > Published, and Raw/Processed/Published is Blob Storage.
When copying to Raw > Processed it converts to csv > Parquet.
The functions set for the additional columns are as follows:
`@concat(formatDateTime(addToTime(utcNow(),9,'Hour'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you would like to convert the datatypes while copying to sink, it is recommended to use Dataflow for any transformations.

In Dataflow activity you can use a derived column to created an additional column for Date and the [toDate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#todate) to covert/cast the data type of that column